# How to check if Kafka is empty using Spring Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When I restart my application I need to process the remaining messages in Kafka until it's empty and then my application should continue to work normally. My problem is how to check if a Kafka topic is empty. I am using Spring Kafka.

Comment: Your question is too broad. By _Kafka_, do you mean a specific Kafka topic? Also, what do you mean by _empty_? Do you want to check if there are no new offsets committed or whether the topic is completely empty?

Comment: Yes, its a specific Kafka topic

Answer (score 1):

Set the `idleEventInterval` container property and you can listen for `ListenerContainerIdleEvents` which will be published each time no records are received during that interval - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#idle-containers).

> While efficient, one problem with asynchronous consumers is detecting when they are idle. You might want to take some action if no messages arrive for some period of time.
>
> You can configure the listener container to publish a ListenerContainerIdleEvent when some time passes with no message delivery. While the container is idle, an event is published every idleEventInterval milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply send a special "restart" message to the topic with a unique identifier or special type (e.g. `type: RESTART`) and configure your Kafka Listener to notify your application (e.g. via a separate Kafka topic) when the "restart" message is received.