# When using KafkaListener, how can I check that a topic message has been read to the end?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

When using @KafkaListener, how can I check that a topic message has been read to the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430893/how-to-check-if-kafka-is-empty-using-spring-kafka/55432339#55432339) about getting an event notification when there are no more records to read.

You can use the `Consumer` in the event to get the current `position()`, and `endOffsets()`; the following shows how to get the end offsets:

```java
@EventListener
void listen(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    System.out.println(event);
    try {
        System.out.println(event.getConsumer().assignment());
        System.out.println(event.getConsumer().endOffsets(event.getConsumer().assignment(), Duration.ofSeconds(5)));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```