# Detecting that the broker is disconnected in Spring Kafka

Tags: spring-kafka

I am trying to write a health check for my Kafka consumer. When the app is up and running I shutdown Kafka and I see lot of

```
 Connection to node 1001 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

in the logs but no ApplicationEvents, error handlers called, nothing. There appears to be no way to call through the listeners to get the NetworkClient state.  My understanding was that there use to be an ApplicationEvent generated when the broker got disconnected. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello I wrote some custom code on how to how to handle this gracefully between a producer and consumer, by sending a `kill-message`  herehttps://stackoverflow.com/a/67542310/6085193 . hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the kafka-clients provide no indication to the caller that the broker is down.

These are the only events available: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#events

You can enable `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`s but you can't tell if the container is just idle, or not connected.

However, you could use the `Consumer` in the event to do some non-destructive call, such as getting the `endOffsets()` for the assigned topics. You will get an exception if the call times out. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329014/when-using-kafkalistener-how-can-i-check-that-a-topic-message-has-been-read-to/67334374#67334374) for an example.

Comment: Got it to work but wouldn't be nice to have a listener.isConnected() in addition isStopped(), isContainerPaused()?  ;-)

Comment: As I said, there is no API provided by the kafka-clients. You can also use an `AdminClient` to describe the cluster.

Comment: but as I know max.block.ms for producer, and I need for Consumer

Comment: Cory, how did u get it to work? Can you provide a code snippet?