# How does a consumer know it is no longer listed in the Kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We have this issue that when Kafka brokers must be taken offline, no consumer service has any idea about that and keeps running.

We tried listing consumers in the new Kafka instance, and saw no existing consumer listed there. All consumers listed are those newly created.

We had to manually terminate all existing consumer services which is not convenient every time we hit this issue.

Question - How does a consumer know it is no longer listed in the Kafka cluster so it should terminate itself?

P.S. We use Spring Kafka.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524678/detecting-that-the-broker-is-disconnected-in-spring-kafka/67524776#67524776

Comment: @GaryRussell great. This is what I'm looking for. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

### 1 -- To Check Clusters & Replica status ?

Check Kafka cluster all broker status

```
$ zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:9001 ls /brokers/ids
```

Check Kafka cluster Specific broker status

```
$ zookeeper-shell.sh localhost:9001 get /brokers/ids/<id>
```

specific to replica_unavailability check

```
$ kafka-check --cluster-type=sample_type replica_unavailability
```

For first broker check

```
$ kafka-check --cluster-type=sample_type --broker-id 3 replica_unavailability --first-broker-only
```

Any partitions replicas not available

```
$ kafka-check --cluster-type=sample_type replica_unavailability
```

Checking offline partitions

```
$ kafka-check --cluster-type=sample_type offline
```

---

### 2 -- Code sample to send/auto-shutdown

> 2 *custom* options to do handle the `shutdown` using a `kill-message`,
> do it gracefully by sending a `kill-message` before taking down
> brokers or topics.
>
> **Option 1**: Consider an in-band message/signal - i.e. *send a “`kill`” message pertaining to topics/brokers consumer is listening to* as it follows the offset order on the topic-partition
>
> **Option 2**: make the consumer listen to `2 topics` for e.g. “`topic`” and “`topic_kill`”

The difference between the 2 options above, is that the first version is comes in the the order it was sent, consider that there *maybe* blocking messages maybe waiting, depending on *your* implementation, to be consumed before that “`kill message`”.

While, the second version allows `kill-signal` to `arrive independently without being blocked` out of band, this is a *nicer & reusable* `architectural pattern`, with a clear separation between data topic and signaling.

> #### Code Sample a) producer sending the kill-message & b) consumer to recieve and handle the shutdown

```
// Producer -- modify and adapt as needed
import json

from kafka import KafkaProducer


producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['0.0.0.0:<my port number>'],
                         key_serializer=lambda m: m.encode('utf8'),
                         value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('utf8'))


def send_kill(topic: str, partitions: [int]):
    
    for p in partitions:
        producer.send(topic, key='kill', partition=p)
    producer.flush()
```

---

```
// Consumer to accept a kill-message -- please modify and adapt as needed
import json

from kafka import KafkaConsumer
from kafka.structs import OffsetAndMetadata, TopicPartition


consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=['0.0.0.0:<my port number>'],
                         key_deserializer=lambda m: m.decode('utf8'),
                         value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('utf8')),
                         auto_offset_reset="earliest",
                         group_id='1')

consumer.subscribe(['topic'])

for msg in consumer:
    tp = TopicPartition(msg.topic, msg.partition)
    offsets = {tp: OffsetAndMetadata(msg.offset, None)}
    
    if msg.key == "kill":
        consumer.commit(offsets=offsets)
        consumer.unsuscribe()
        exit(0)
  
    # do your work...
    
    consumer.commit(offsets=offsets)
```

Comment: I don't think I follow your answer, but my problem is the other way I believe: 

Kafka cluster gets re-launched from scratch (worst case scenario in real world), but consumers have no idea about that and keep running.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524678/detecting-that-the-broker-is-disconnected-in-spring-kafka/67524776#67524776