# ExponentialBackOff with KafkaMessageListenerContainer when kafka not reachable

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to attach `ExponentialBackOff` to `KafkaMessageListenerContainer` (in batch mode so I can't use `RetryTemplate` on `KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` ).

Then I set wrong broker of Kafka, but when starting the program it keeps spamming

> Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be
> established. Broker may not be available.
> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient  ... Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

```
@Bean
    public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> adapter(KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container) {
            KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<String, String> adapter =
                    new KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter<>(container, KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch);
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container() {
        ContainerProperties properties = ..;
          
    
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container = new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf() , properties);
    
        ExponentialBackOff expBackOff = new ExponentialBackOff(200000, 1.5);
        expBackOff.setMaxInterval(6000000);
        kafkaContainer.setCommonErrorHandler(new DefaultErrorHandler(expBackOff));
    
            return container;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The backoff (error handler) only applies when the listener throws an exception.

Spring has no control over the connection to the cluster; that is all internal to the `kafka-clients` - no indication is provided by the client to Spring that the broker is not available.

Comment: But error handler is set on the KafkaMessageListenerContainer, what am I missing? how to make it throw exception?

Comment: As I said, it is out of Spring's control; when the broker is not available, no exception is thrown by the client.

Comment: I see, any workaround? I don't want to hit brokers ip all the time.

Comment: See this answer for some suggestions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524678/detecting-that-the-broker-is-disconnected-in-spring-kafka/67524776#67524776

Comment: Thanks, not sure  that I will use it :(

Comment: It also means, that if I switch to KafkaMessageSource will get same problem as it also uses same kafka-client, correct?

Comment: Yes, it is the only client available.

Comment: looks like this causes issue for me, in scenario when topic doesn't not exists, I see in the log prints: `org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient topic=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` dozens per second!

Comment: Yes, again, this is all internal to the client code. You can make it fail faster by reducing `max.block.ms` from its default of 60,000.

Comment: I see that it also not able to catch  `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to load SSL keystore` this is Exception....

Comment: One more time; this is all internal to the kafka-clients, and Spring has no control over it - if you have concerns, I suggest you raise them with the Apache Kafka folks on one of their mailing lists or their JIRA.

Comment: last question if you don't mind, which types of errors, `KafkaMessageListenerContainer.setCommonErrorHandler()` will handle?

Comment: Any exceptions thrown by your listener. Exceptions thrown by the consumer (e.g. deserialization errors) go to `handleOtherException()`. This can be avoided by using an `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` which allows such exceptions to be handled the same as listener exceptions.