# Monitor Kafka Consumer Lag and generate Alerts

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How do I monitor Kafka consumer lag and generate emails/alerts ?Below is my requirement

1. I want to trigger an email when a messages older than 1 day on the topic .

I am using Spring boot micro services ,Java 8

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig 
{
    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;
 
    @Value(value = "${general.topic.group.id}")
    private String groupId;
 
    @Value(value = "${user.topic.group.id}")
    private String userGroupId;
 
    // 1. Consume string data from Kafka
 
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<Integer, String>  consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, 
                StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
    
    
 
    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String>>
                        kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Integer, String> factory =
                                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(3);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
    }
    
 //not compiling
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> m1()
    {
        ContainerProperties containerProps = new ContainerProperties("topic1", "topic2");
        containerProps.setMessageListener(new MessageListener<Integer, String>() { 
 
            @Override
            public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> data) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                
            }
           
        });
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<Integer, String> cf =
                                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerFactory()); //not compiling
        KafkaMessageListenerContainer<Integer, String> container =
                                new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProps);
        return container;
    }
```

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67329014/when-using-kafkalistener-how-can-i-check-that-a-topic-message-has-been-read-to/67334374#67334374

Comment: @GaryRussell can u show an working example.. he is what i tried 
https://pastebin.com/NYUTik2J

Comment: @GaryRussell my requiremnet is suppose i did not read offset number 7 but read offset 8,9,,...so on and message offset 7 is there on topic for 1 day then how can i trigger an alert .I am using PCF and Spring boot

Comment: For starters, my question would be how do you know offset 7 was not read? And if it was not read, then why would you commit that offset to enable to consumer to continue with 8 and 9? Secondly, you'd need some other consumer process to go back through the data you've read by the primary consumer to double-check if it was actually read or not and check the timestamps (older than a day)?

Comment: would be how do you know offset 7 was not read--that's what i want to solve.
I am new to Consumer API .I am still reading documents .So if i don't read offset 7 and commit i won't be able to go to offset 8 and so on ?Is that  correct?

Comment: No; it is not correct. Kafka maintains 2 values for a consumerGroup/partition - the committed offset (where the consumer will start if restarted) and position - which record will be returned on the next poll, regardless of whether a previous offset was committed. Committing an offset only affects the committed offset, not the position. Spring provides a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` to reposition if the listener throws an exception. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) instead of trying to write your own solution.

Comment: it requires GO.And my app is Java based deployed on cloud.And i cant find burrow on maven

Comment: @Pale Burrow doesn't require anything unless you're trying to build the project. It's a standalone executable. And it can monitor lag for all applications, not only your Java ones, therefore that's generally what most people use

Comment: This answer doesn't really address how to set up alerting, though, which could be done with Prometheus AlertManager and Prometheus scraping Burrow

Comment: @OneCricketeer my requiremnet is suppose i did not offset  number 7 but read  offsert 8,9,,...so on and message offset 7 is there on topic for 1 day then how can i trigger an alert .I am using PCF and Spring boot