# Spring Kafka: Close the container and read the messages from specific offset with ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In my spring kafka application, I want to trigger the consumer at run time according to input of some scheduler. Scheduler will tell the listener from which topic it can start consuming messages. There is springboot application with custom `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` class. I need to perform three tasks:

1. close the container, After successfully reading all the messages available on topic.
2. It will store the current offset in DB or file system.
3. Next time when consumer up again, the stored offset can be used to process the records instead of default offset managed by Kafka. So that in future we can change the offset value in DB and get get desired reports.
   I know how to handle all these with `@KafkaListener` but not sure how to hook with `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory`. The current code is listed below:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaApp{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("testTopic").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

     }

     @Component
     class Listener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);

    private static final Method otherListen;

    static {
        try {
            otherListen = Listener.class.getDeclaredMethod("otherListen", List.class);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }

    private final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;

    private final MessageHandlerMethodFactory methodFactory;

    private final KafkaAdmin admin;

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    public Listener(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory, KafkaAdmin admin,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor<?, ?> bpp) {

        this.factory = factory;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.template = template;
        this.methodFactory = bpp.getMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "myId", topics = "testTopic")
    public void listen(String topicName) {
        try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(this.admin.getConfigurationProperties())) {
            NewTopic topic = TopicBuilder.name(topicName).build();
            client.createTopics(List.of(topic)).all().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to create topic", e);
        }
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container =
                this.factory.createContainer(new TopicPartitionOffset(topicName, 0));
        BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter<String, String> adapter =
                new BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter<>(this, otherListen);
        adapter.setHandlerMethod(new HandlerAdapter(
                this.methodFactory.createInvocableHandlerMethod(this, otherListen)));
        FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter<String, String> filtered =
                new FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter<>(adapter, record -> !record.key().equals("foo"));
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(filtered);
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("group.for." + topicName);
        container.setBeanName(topicName + ".container");
        container.start();
        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> this.template.send(topicName, 0, i % 2 == 0 ? "foo" : "bar", "test" + i));
    }

    void otherListen(List<String> others) {
        log.info("Others: {}", others);
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class KafkaApp{


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("testTopic").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

     }

     @Component
     class Listener {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);

    private static final Method otherListen;

    static {
        try {
            otherListen = Listener.class.getDeclaredMethod("otherListen", List.class);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }

    private final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory;

    private final MessageHandlerMethodFactory methodFactory;

    private final KafkaAdmin admin;

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> template;

    public Listener(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory, KafkaAdmin admin,
            KafkaTemplate<String, String> template, KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor<?, ?> bpp) {

        this.factory = factory;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.template = template;
        this.methodFactory = bpp.getMessageHandlerMethodFactory();
    }

    @KafkaListener(id = "myId", topics = "testTopic")
    public void listen(String topicName) {
        try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(this.admin.getConfigurationProperties())) {
            NewTopic topic = TopicBuilder.name(topicName).build();
            client.createTopics(List.of(topic)).all().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to create topic", e);
        }
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container =
                this.factory.createContainer(new TopicPartitionOffset(topicName, 0));
        BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter<String, String> adapter =
                new BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter<>(this, otherListen);
        adapter.setHandlerMethod(new HandlerAdapter(
                this.methodFactory.createInvocableHandlerMethod(this, otherListen)));
        FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter<String, String> filtered =
                new FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter<>(adapter, record -> !record.key().equals("foo"));
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(filtered);
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("group.for." + topicName);
        container.setBeanName(topicName + ".container");
        container.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(3000L); 
        container.start();
        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> this.template.send(topicName, 0, i % 2 == 0 ? "foo" : "bar", "test" + i));
    }

    void otherListen(List<String> others) {
        log.info("Others: {}", others);
    }
     @EventListener
    public void eventHandler(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        logger.info("No messages received for " + event.getIdleTime() + " milliseconds");
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can receive `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`s when there are no messages left to process; you can use this event to stop the container; you should perform the `stop()` on a different thread (not the one that publishes the event).

See [How to check if Kafka is empty using Spring Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55430893/how-to-check-if-kafka-is-empty-using-spring-kafka/55432339#55432339)

You can get the partition/offset in several ways.

```java
void otherListen<List<ConsumerRecord<..., ...>>)
```

or

```java
void otherListen(List<String> others,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION) List<Integer> partitions,
    @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets)
```

You can specify the starting offset in the

```java
new TopicPartitionOffset(topicName, 0), startOffset);
```

when creating the container.

**EDIT**

To stop the container when it is idle, set the `idleEventInterval` and add an `@EventListener` method and stop the container.

```java
TaskExecutor exec = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();

@EventListener
void idle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    log...
    this.exec.execute(() -> event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class).stop());
}
```

If you add `concurrency` to your containers, you would need for each child container to go idle before stopping the parent container.

**EDIT2**

I just added it to the code I wrote for the answer to your other question and it works exactly as expected.

```java
    @KafkaListener(id = "so69134055", topics = "so69134055")
    public void listen(String topicName) {
        try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(this.admin.getConfigurationProperties())) {
            NewTopic topic = TopicBuilder.name(topicName).build();
            client.createTopics(List.of(topic)).all().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to create topic", e);
        }
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> container =
                this.factory.createContainer(new TopicPartitionOffset(topicName, 0));
        BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter<String, String> adapter =
                new BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter<>(this, otherListen);
        adapter.setHandlerMethod(new HandlerAdapter(
                this.methodFactory.createInvocableHandlerMethod(this, otherListen)));
        FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter<String, String> filtered =
                new FilteringBatchMessageListenerAdapter<>(adapter, record -> !record.key().equals("foo"));
        container.getContainerProperties().setMessageListener(filtered);
        container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("group.for." + topicName);
        container.getContainerProperties().setIdleEventInterval(3000L);
        container.setBeanName(topicName + ".container");
        container.start();
        IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> this.template.send(topicName, 0, i % 2 == 0 ? "foo" : "bar", "test" + i));
    }

    void otherListen(List<String> others) {
        log.info("Others: {}", others);
    }

    TaskExecutor exec = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();

    @EventListener
    public void idle(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
        log.info(event.toString());
        this.exec.execute(() -> {
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer container = event.getContainer(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.class);
            log.info("stopping container: " + container.getBeanName());
            container.stop();
        });
    }
```

```
[foo.container-0-C-1] Others: [test0, test2, test4, test6, test8]
[foo.container-0-C-1] ListenerContainerIdleEvent [idleTime=5.007s, listenerId=foo.container-0, container=KafkaMessageListenerContainer [id=foo.container-0, clientIndex=-0, topicPartitions=[foo-0]], paused=false, topicPartitions=[foo-0]]
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] stopping container: foo.container
[foo.container-0-C-1] [Consumer clientId=consumer-group.for.foo-2, groupId=group.for.foo] Unsubscribed all topics or patterns and assigned partitions
[foo.container-0-C-1] Metrics scheduler closed
[foo.container-0-C-1] Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter
[foo.container-0-C-1] Metrics reporters closed
[foo.container-0-C-1] App info kafka.consumer for consumer-group.for.foo-2 unregistered
[foo.container-0-C-1] group.for.foo: Consumer stopped
```

Comment: Thanks @Gary, I have edited the code above to incorporate to close the container but it doesn't seem to work. I have added the 'setIdleEventInterval' and EventListener as you suggested.

Comment: You are not doing anything except logging in the event handler; you need to stop the container (asynchronously to avoid a delay).

Comment: Thanks @Gary, I mean to say that  method  annotated with 'EventListener' is not getting invoked. I am not able to see the logger and even debugger is not going on to that method after waiting till idle time. Please help

Comment: FYI: I am using Kafka version: 2.7.1

Comment: I just added it to the code I wrote for your other question, and it works fine for me so something is wrong with your code. See the second edit.

Comment: 2.7.6 is the latest, but there are no changes in this area.